# Events with Socket.io not being executed in the order they were receieved

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am emitting events in the following order:

```
Socket.emit('waiting','waiting for someone');
Socket.emit('found','found someone');
```

On the client side, I'm listening to events like this:

```
socket.on('waiting',function(data)
{
   alert(data);
});

socket.on('found',function(data)
{
   alert(data);
});
```

But yet for some reason, I see an alert for 'Found someone' before 'waiting for someone'. Although when I look at the console, the events seem to be emitted in the correct order. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: same I have noticed